# Splunk to take the second queries result(field) into first query for Percentage Memory of Linux host

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I am a newbie to SplunK.

I am trying to pull the `Memory %` of my Linux hosts which belong to a particular group called `Database_hosts`.

I am able to get the `Memory %` of a particular host if I provide that explicitly as `host="host01.example.com"` however, I'm looking to run this query against multiple hosts.

Multiple hosts which belong to `Database_hosts` group I can extract from the `inputlookup cmdb_host.csv` in Splunk.

Now, I can extract the hosts from `inputlookup cmdb_host.csv` where it contains the hosts in `name` field but I am clueless how to put my second query into my first query ie `sourcetype=top pctMEM=* host="host01.example.com"`

Both the queries working independently though.

My first query:

```
sourcetype=top pctMEM=* host="host01" OR host="host02"
| multikv 
| dedup host
| rex field=pctMEM "(?<usage>\d+)" 
| where usage> 40
| table  host pctMEM
```

Result on run:

[image]

and this is my second query:

```
| inputlookup cmdb_host.csv
| search support_group="Database_hosts" NOT (fqdn IN("ap*", "aw*",""))
| table name
```

Result on run:

[image]

How I can use my second query output field `name` into first query's `host=` field?

Any help will be much appreciated.

**EDIT**: just tried but no luck:

```
sourcetype=top pctMEM=* host="[inputlookup cmdb_host.csv where support_group="Database_hosts" | table name] 
| multikv 
| dedup name
| rex field=pctMEM "(?<usage>\d+)" 
| where usage>20
| table  name pctMEM
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're very close.  If you run the subsearch (the part inside square brackets) by itself and add `| format` then you'll see what is returned to the main search.  It'll look something like `((name=host01) OR (name=host02))`.  Combining that with the main search produces:

```
sourcetype=top pctMEM=* host=((name=host01) OR (name=host02))
| multikv 
| dedup name
| rex field=pctMEM "(?<usage>\d+)" 
| where usage>20
| table  name pctMEM
```

which won't work.  It can be fixed by renaming `name` to `host` in the subsearch and letting the subsearch create the expression.

```
sourcetype=top pctMEM=* [|inputlookup cmdb_host.csv where support_group="Database_hosts" 
  | return 100 host=name]
| multikv 
| dedup name
| rex field=pctMEM "(?<usage>\d+)" 
| where usage>20
| table  name pctMEM
```

The `return` command tells Splunk to return up to 100 results and rename `name` to `host`.  It's equivalent to `fields name | rename name as host | format`.

Comment: RichG, Thanks for the detailed answer and +1 for the same however, i'm surprise it runs and doesn't returns any results.

Comment: Double-check the query.  Make sure all field names are correct and match those in the index and the lookup file.  If there were typos in the OP then those same typos may be in my answer.  When that checks out debug the query by running one statement at a time and verifying the results are as expected.  Start with the subsearch.

Comment: Sure, let me try your first approach.

Comment: RichG, when i'm running simply `sourcetype=top pctMEM=* host="host01"| multikv | dedup host| rex field=pctMEM "(?<usage>\d+)" | table  host pctMEM`  it producing the correct output, i am not able to debug it.

Comment: If the query is producing the correct output then there's no need to debug.  If it is *not* producing the correct output then debugging is needed.  Run the first statement `sourcetype=top pctMEM=* host="host01"` and confirm the output is correct.  If it is not correct then you're at the faulty statement; if it works then add the next command (`multikv`), continuing the process until you find the line that generates the undesired results.

Comment: RichG, thanks ..  i see `| dedup name` is creating mess if there is no duplicates then it just not returns anything which i suspect after following your approach and when i removed that its worked like a charm!  I need to Know why this `dedup` making mess. Much thanks again for the nice lesson and making my day!

Comment: `dedup` should not make a mess and shouldn't change anything if there are no duplicate values in the specified field(s).  At least you have it working now.

Comment: RichG, true `dedupe`  by funtion should not make a mess but this is what i'm observing after testing all the statement one by one and multiple times, even if there are duplicates it should remove them and move forward to do rest of the job but that i failed to understand here in my case.